# Is that secure to keep sensitive data in SQLite

Tags: android

Is this secure to keep sensitive data like pins, passwords using build in SQLite database?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3140230/sqlite-database-security

Answer (score 3):

In theory, an SQLite database created by your application will be visible from your application, but not from outside the application -- see [**Using Databases**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db).

Still, I suppose that, one way or another, someone could retrieve that database *(using some FileExplorer on a rooted device, or [using ADB](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#sqlite))* -- so, it might be wise to at least encrypt the sensitive data.

Answer (score 1):

There is a similar question already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259561/encrypt-sqlite-database-in-c)

Basically, you can use System.Data.Sqlite wrapper, which includes encryption

Answer (score 0):

SQLite is not itself encrypted.  If you store text in a SQLite database, you should assume anyone with access to the device has access to the text.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite data encryption is possible, [for more detail see this](http://www.hwaci.com/sw/sqlite/see.html).