# Offline storage for mobile app- Data transfer to cloud- publish to app store. Need an advise

Tags: sqlite, react-native, local-storage, app-store, mobile-application

I am going to build a mobile app for my dad which will have four tables namely- buyer table , seller table , buyer balance payment table and seller due payment table. I have thought of using Reactive Native and SQLite due to its offline data storage capability.

Transaction limit per day will be between 2-10 rows in buyer and seller table.

Can anyone advise whether the offline data storage is safe?

Can anyone read the data from phone storage or its hidden inside the app?

Is it possible to export/import the data weekly to personal cloud storage like google drive or Microsoft one-drive and vice versa?

Is it advisable to publish such apps to app store or can i use it without publishing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the app is for personal use, u don't have to publish in play store. You can create apk and install in your phone.

SQLite storage is adequate for offline storage but u might lose data if backup of the data is not been taken.

[Encrypt your data before you enter it in the database. As far as I know, the SQLite database is kept in a single file somewhere in the /data/ directory. What is more, your data is kept in plain text format. This means that it will always be possible for someone to extract that data by rooting the phone, obtaining the .db SQLite file and opening it with a text editor.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3140230/sqlite-database-security)

If the data is sensitive, you should consider encryption.
Yes, you can take backup and storage as encrypted file in cloud.

In my personal opinion, you can use firebase or other free cloud websites to host your data. It will be more simple and secure.